# Running a python flask app from button on desktop

Tags: python, user-interface, flask, server, localhost

I have developed a python Flask application, which I am currently running on my PC. I start the localhost server by running my file `app.py`. When connecting to the localhost via a browser, a UI can be accessed.

Now the question. The goal is to make it possible for someone who does not have any experience in python (and programming in general) to use my application. My idea was to install all the requirements on their laptop, and make a button on their desktop that starts the application, and opens the browser while connecting to the localhost port. So in principle this would be executing `python app.py`, but not from a command line or IDE.

Is this possible? I want to avoid unnessesary complexity as much as possible.

I have tried looking into servers but I think it might not be needed.

Comment: Why are you not hosting the website if it is a browser app? Anyway, how is the project organized are you using a `setup.py`, `pyproject.toml` or something similar to resolve all dependencies? There are many options to achieve your goal, but it will be OS-dependent. Except if the user is required to have a running Python interpreter and a package manager like pip.

Comment: I want to avoid extra security measurements which would come up when hosting. The project currently has no `setup.py` and `pyproject.toml`, and the OS would be windows. Currently I am not resolving dependencies, and I could install a python interpreter and package manager or create a virtual environment on their machine.